# loop logic to prevent stack overflow

Tags: java, loops, logic

I have a loop which tries to give three tries for an url. Is there another way of calling the function other than an inner loop. The list of urls is long and I fear the stack may overflow. I have tried hard and this is not for Homework. The tries counter is properly incremented no problem in that area

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tries = 0;
                theURL = line;
                String escape = URLEncoder.encode(line, "UTF-8");
                url = cache + escape;
                while(tries < 3) {
                    getTimeStamp(url);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Loops don't cause stack overflows - unbounded nested function calls do that.

Answer (score 3):

You're never incrementing `tries` - your `while` loop is infinite.

Hence it will trigger a `StackOverflowError` at some point.

Comment: The tries is incremented in the right places in another part of the code.

Comment: @MallikKumar If it is incremented somewhere else, then your loop is useless, and will still go on forever if `tries < 3` (and your example not self-contained). You should consider incrementing within the scope of the loop.

Comment: Even if I incremented tries within the loop...there  is still the problem of  stack overflow after a few hundred urls...

Comment: @MallikKumar maybe something in the body of your `getTimeStamp` method? Hard to know whether pertaining to this question or another question.

Comment: If you are incrementing properly, what do you think is going to make the stack overflow? You don't seem to be doing very much... unless it's your `cache` variable, or whatever `getTimestamp` does.

In short, I think you need to post more of your code to make things clearer.

Comment: Exactly.I am inc loop in the body of getTimeStamp.I forgot to mention that tries is  a static variable.

Comment: Does `getTimeStamp` call back to this code? Stack overflows don't happen because you call methods many times in a loop, they occur because of deeply nested recursive calls. There's no recursion here, is there?

Comment: Just as a stylistic thing, I wouldn't do that (increment a static variable in the called method) -- exactly because it's confusing to someone reading the code. Instead, I'd put the increment in the loop after the method call.

Or you might be better with a `for` loop.